# mac mysql terminal doesn't ask for password ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, xampp, passwords, mariadb

mysql database terminal supposed to ask me for password right after I typed 'mysql -u root -p'
Instead, it says "-->" after the command..

> Last login: Tue Nov 27 16:00:34 on ttys000
>  Hyewons-iMac:~
>   home-mac$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql ; exit;
>   Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>  Your
>   MariaDB connection id is 6
>  Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB Source
>   distribution
>  Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB
>   Corporation Ab and others.
>  Type 'help;' or '\h' for help.
>   Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>  MariaDB
>   [(none)]> mysql -u root -p 
>       ->

so I typed

> ;

after

> -->

it goes

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p' at line 1
>  MariaDB [(none)]>

I have used mysql for WINDOWS and have never experienced it before..
what should I do??

I installed latest XAMPP 7.2.12-0 ( mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64 also..) on MAC 10.12.6.
MySQL Database didn't work so changing mysql port to 3307 worked. Then I opened xampp > xamppfiles > bin > mysql
I have never set up for host name or password. I don't know I am doing right..

Comment: You are trying to start the mysql shell from within the mysql shell. Type `SHOW DATABASES;` instead and you will see that you're already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

After typing this shell command:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

The prompt changes from `$` (or `#`) to:

```
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

At that point, you should type SQL statements, not try to re-enter the "mysql" commandline tool.

The "shell" is very much like "cmd" in Windows, so I am surprised that you went astray.